Trying to use Image.Source for MultiBinding gives the "An attribute name is missing" error
I'm unsure whether this is my fault, or something weird's going on.
Here's my code:
<Image
    Width="12" 
    Height="12"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Margin="0,2,0,0"
                                        
    <Image.Source>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CachedImageLoaderWithIndex}">
            <Binding Path="ObjectSpriteIndex" Mode="OneWay"/>
         </MultiBinding>
    </Image.Source>
/>

I'm trying to load an Image's source with the MultiBinding thingy, but Visual Studio is marking it as an error. It says "An attribute name is missing" on <Image.Source>
I'm not sure whether it is my fault or something else.

UWP does not have MultiBinding. Why would you want to use it at all when there is only a single Binding?
